# How to get value from select using javascript

Tags: javascript, prestashop

```js
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
        var valueFromForm;
        valueFromForm = document.getElementById("group_2").value;

    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
        quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
    else
        quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + valueFromForm).trigger('keyup');
    else
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);

    $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_2" id="group_2" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">                                                                 <option value="18" selected="selected" title="35">35</option>
<option value="19" title="36">36</option>
<option value="20" title="37">37</option>
<option value="21" title="38">38</option>
<option value="22" title="39">39</option>
<option value="23" title="40">40</option>
</select>
```

I have a drop down list and I want to get value. Next, add this value into quantity.

Look at valueFromForm variable. And this is a Prestashop 1.6 where I want to use it. To test this code You can choose "Size" attribute.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what element is product_quantity_up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get selected use           **$('#group_2 :selected').val();**

you are making your code a little more complicated

why use vanilla JS like *document.getElementById("group_2").value;* inside Jquery ??

Comment: I add to jquery valueFromForm = $('#group_2 :selected').val(); but it dosent work. What I do wrong ?

Comment: debug... conole.log( $('#group_2 :selected').val() ) let us know what was the output

Answer (score 0):

I have placed some changers to your code but I have no idea what are the following values,

allowBuyWhenOutOfStock
quantityAvailable
fieldName

now the code is ruining try it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allowBuyWhenOutOfStock = true
  var quantityAvailable = 100
  $(document).change(function(e) {        
    var valueFromForm;
    valueFromForm = document.getElementById("group_2").value;
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0) {
      quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
    } else {
      quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
    }
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT) {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + valueFromForm).trigger('keyup');
    } else {
      console.log(fieldName + " " + quantityAvailableT)
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(quantityAvailableT);
    }
    $('#quantity_wanted').change();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_2" id="group_2" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
<option value="18" selected="selected"title="35">35</option>
<option value="19" title="36">36</option>
<option value="20" title="37">37</option>
<option value="21" title="38">38</option>
<option value="22" title="39">39</option>
<option value="23" title="40">40</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this jsBin to see how the get should work in your case:

[JsBin example](https://jsbin.com/sonifagucu/edit?html,output)

But after all:

- get value of a select element: `$("#group_2").val();`
- get text of the selected option: `$("#group_2").find("option:selected").text();`
- get other attributes of the selected option: `$("#group_2").find("option:selected").attr("title");`

In your case:

`var valueFromForm = $("#group_2").val();`

I can also suggest to check the "keyUp" event that is attached to the input field becasue the end of your jQuery chain there is this: `.trigger('keyup')`